# Calling a method from a user control which is implemented in a different location

Tags: c#, asp.net, oop, user-controls

I have created a user control as FormPicker.ascx. I included it to AdmissionPicker.aspx page using the below code segment.

```
<%@ Register Src="~/Common/Controls/FormPicker.ascx" TagName="FormPicker"
TagPrefix="uc1" %>

<div>
<uc1:FormPicker ID="FormPicker" Width="100%"
runat="server" AddAny="True" />
</div>
```

Inside FormPicker.ascx.cs I am calling the below function. LoadAdmissionData() is implemented in AdmissionPicker.aspx.cs

```
var admitCtrl = new AdmissionPicker();
admitCtrl.LoadAdmissionData();
```

LoadAdmissionData() method contains a drop down list. Drop down list is implemented in AdmissionPicker.aspx.

```
public void LoadAdmissionData()
{
  int val=DropDownList.SelectedIndex();
}
```

I am using LoadAdmissionData() method in the same page and now I need to call it from FormPicker.ascx.cs. When calling it it does not identify the DropDownList. How to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hi can u please change this line

```
var admitCtrl = new AdmissionPicker();
```

to

```
var admitCtrl = (AdmissionPicker) Page;
```

Comment: @izadi Actually I am using        var admitCtrl = new operations.app.com.web.Sec1.Controls.AdmissionPicker(); when creating the object.(I am using the full namespace in order to call it purposely) Can you guide me how to change this to var admitCtrl = (AdmissionPicker) Page;

Comment: @izadi | I edited the code like this. Is this what you meant | But it says syntax error | Please corrent me if Iam wrong . var admitCtrl = new (app.hospicecom.com.web.Sec1.Controls.AdmissionPicker) Page;

Comment: Please copy and paste this line `var admitCtrl = (app.hospicecom.com.web.Sec1.Controls.AdmissionPicker) Page;`

Comment: @harsha you have  created new object from ur page its wrong u should get current page that ur usercontrol has loaded on this